# Excel - look if values in my excel sheet in Column A, exists in Column B in another excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry I'm a newbie in excel, I just want a formula that can determine if the values on my column A in excelDoc.xls exists in my column B in excelDoc2.xls. I have no idea how to do that. I want to be able to print on my column C, if there's a match in excelDoc2.xls

This is what i tried, but doesnt work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A1530,'[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527,3,FALSE),"No Match")
```

also, I dont want it to be case sensitive.. uppercases and lowercases shouldnt be a problem when looking for a match.. is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i just figured if theres a way using vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MATCH()` to simply look for a value in a column, so try something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1, '[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527, FALSE)), "Not Found", "Found")
```

Put this formula at the top of the column and then copy down for all the values you want to check.

Incidentally, VLOOKUP, MATCH and text comparison in Excel is case-insensitive, so "abC" would match "AbC" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the number 3? Do you mean to be using that or are you trying to return the same field?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A1530,'[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527,1,FALSE),"No Match")
```

will return the cell contents from column B.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A1530,'[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527,TRUE,FALSE),"No Match")
```

will return a `TRUE` statement if there is a match.

Also, do you need the `IFERROR`? I would think to use `ISNA`

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A1530,'[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527,TRUE,FALSE)),"No Match",VLOOKUP(A1:A1530,'[excelDoc2.xlsx]HTM-JS-INC'!$B1:$B527,TRUE,FALSE))
```